# Method execution from another object in C++

Tags: c++, oop, stm32

First of all allow me to introduce a little bit of my class structure. I am designing a little library for an ARM device (STM32) and I want to implement a couple of objects defining the different peripheral available on the system.

```
class xGPIO : public Peripheral 
{
public:
    xGPIO();
    xGPIO(GPIO_TypeDef * GPIOx1, uint16_t Pinx1);
    virtual ~xGPIO();

    void on(void);
    void off(void);
private:
    void xInitGPIO(void);

};
```

The idea I have in mind is to implement an internal public function named **callback** which sets which function is the next to be called on my timer object. However this function will for sure be a method defined in another class and I want it to be executed from xTimer. The behaviour here, should be that whenever the Timer ends its countdown, it should call the function stored by the programmer in the callBack method.

```
class xTimer : public Peripheral 
{
public:
    xTimer(TIM_TypeDef * tim);
    virtual ~xTimer();
    /* void callBack(void (*f)()); */

private:
    void xInitTimer(void);
    TIM_HandleTypeDef htim;
};

void xTimer::callBack(void (*f)())
{
   f();
}
```

The code under main.cpp woudl be as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    mySYS->initialize(false);

    xGPIO myGreenLed (GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0);

    /* Declare Timers.  */
    xTimer myTimer(TIM2);    
    // myTimer.callBack(myGreenLed.on);
}
```

Any clues on how to solve this issue? Is there an easy way to comply with that design on a C++ program?

Comment: It is almost, but not 100% clear what you want to do. If the timer is supposed to call a previously set callback, then why does the `void xTimer::callBack(void (*f)())` take a function as parameter? Isnt the timer supposed to know what function to call in advance?

Comment: do you need one timer to handle all callbacks or can it be different timers for each callback ?

Comment: The title is rather misleading. You don't want to call the method of another _class_, you want to call the method of another _object_, here `myGreenLed`. This is critically important: if `xGPIO::on` was a `static` class method (i.e. didn't need an object), you could convert `&xGPIO::on` to `void(*)()`.

Comment: @MSalters you are right, corrected.

Comment: @tobi303 I can have several timers. This is a preliminary design, the final one should save the function into a local pointer (or similar) and execute it when the event takes place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using C patterns. C++ has the far more powerful `std::function`. Your `xTimer::callBack` should be defined as

```
void xTimer::callBack(std::function<void(void)> f) { f(); }
```

so it can be called as

```
myTimer.callBack([&](){myGreenLed.on()}); //using lambda
```

or

```
myTimer.callBack(std::bind(&xGPIO::on, &myGreenLed));
```

Comment: `std::function` does dynamic allocation, so not always a good idea on a bare-metal system if this functionality may be used from interrupts (this also includes the place where the objects will be "destructed"). It may be better to provide functors constructed manually on the stack or as global variables. Just a thing to remember, as I'm not against C++ at all (in fact I'm writing a C++ RTOS for such microcontrollers - http://distortos.org/ ).

Comment: @FreddieChopin: Technically speaking almost anything in C++ may do dynamic allocation at any point. Practically speaking, _calling_ `std::function` won't do a dynamic allocation.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "calling". Executing bound function will not do any dynamic allocation. But construction, copy or desctruction use `new` and `delete`. We don't know how OP wants to use it (maybe the callbacks would be disposed of right after use - in interrupt? maybe the callbacks will be added from other interrupts?), so I just put a note so he would be aware of the fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without `std::function` when using templates directly:

```
template<class T>
class xTimer : public Peripheral 
{
public:
    xTimer(TIM_TypeDef * tim);
    virtual ~xTimer();
    void callBack(T &obj, void (*T::f)())
    {
        (obj.*f)();
    }

private:
    void xInitTimer(void);
    TIM_HandleTypeDef htim;
};
```

and can be used like:

```
xTimer<xGPIO> myTimer(TIM2);    
myTimer.callBack(myGreenLed, &xGPIO::on);
```

You're then losing the flexibility of `std::function`, and that it does not work with `std::bind` and lambdas then, but gain the advantage that there is no allocation/deallocation.

The template can be also just on the `callback` level instead, but I suppose that you would actually want to store the value and call it later, then you'd need to templatize the storage.

If your called method would only be member of a specific single type (i.e. always `xGPIO`), then you wouldn't even need the template.

Also beware that if you store the object instance to be called later, you must ensure that the object lifetime remains until you need to call it (or you'd need to make a copy, use `std::shared_ptr` etc.). That also applies to use of `std::function` with and object pointer or `std::ref`.