# how to safely use std::function in interrupts handlers on emended system?

Tags: c++, stl, stm32, interrupt-handling

I'm Working with STM33F103, and I'm trying to implement a callback mechanism that would  call methods on a given object to handle interrupts, so far I use the following solution:

```
class Nvic
{
public:
   using function_pointer =void (*)(void);  

   template<typename T>
   static void get_interrupt(int interrupt_number, T* object,void (T::*methode)())
   {
       class_vector[interrupt_number]=reinterpret_cast<Default_class*>(object);
       method_vector[interrupt_number]=reinterpret_cast<default_method_type>(methode);
   }

   static void execute_interrupt(int interrupt_number)
   {
       (class_vector[interrupt_number]->*method_vector[interrupt_number])();
   }
private:
   struct Default_class{void default_method();};
   using default_method_type =void(Default_class::*)(void);

   static inline Default_class* class_vector[NUMBER_OF_INTERRUPTS];
   static inline default_method_type method_vector[NUMBER_OF_INTERRUPTS];
}

extern "C"
{
void Some_ISR(void) __attribute__ ((interrupt));    
void Some_ISR(void){Nvic::execute_interrupt(2);}
}
```

And if some object want to bind interrupt to itself:

```
class Some_class
{
public:
    Some_class(int peripherial_iterrupt)
    {
         Nvic::get_interrupt(peripherial_iterrupt,this,&Some_class::my_interrupt);
    }

private:
    my_interrupt();

};
```

But I want to implement this based on `std::function`, unfortunately it turns out that [`std::function` can dynamically allocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225069/method-execution-from-another-object-in-c) so it is not reentrant.
So is there any way to make sure that `std::function` is interrupt safe?

Maybe using an allocator will solve the problem, if I provide `std::function`, my custom allocator which allocates memory in some static memory buffer there will be no interrupt heap corruption problem.

Or maybe if I provide newlib-nano `__malloc_lock` and `__mallock_free` functions then heap memory allocation will be interrupt safe.

It also may allow me to use other STL containers and algorithms in interrupt safe environment, like this:

```
class Some_interface :private Some_peripherial
{
public:
    Some_interface(int peripherial_number) :Some_peripherial(peripherial_number)
    {
        int interrupt_number =peripherial_number;   
        Nvic::get_interrupt(interrupt_number,this,&Some_interface::interrupt_routine);
    }
    void send_data(void* buff, size_t size)
    {
        for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            data_to_send.push_back((uint8_t)buff[i]);
        }
    }

    void set_all_data_send_callback(std::function<void(void)> f){all_data_send_callback=f;}

private:
    std::vector<uint8_t> data_to_send;
    std::function<void(void)> all_data_send_callback;

    void interrupt_routine()
    {
        if(data_to_send.empty()){if(all_data_send_callback)all_data_send_callback();};
        else
        {
            Some_peripherial::send(data_to_send.back());
            data_to_send.pop_back();
        }       
    }
};

class Timer_task :private Timer_peripherial
{
public:
    Timer_task(int peripherial_number) :Timer_peripherial(peripherial_number)
    {
        int interrupt_number =peripherial_number;   
        Nvic::get_interrupt(interrupt_number,this,&Timer_task ::on_interrupt);
        Timer_peripherial::set_interrupt_on_evry_10ms();
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void set_task(T* object,void (T::*methode)())
    {
        task =std::bind(std::mem_fn(methode),object);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(void)> task;
    void on_interrupt()
    {
        if(task) task();
    }
};

Some_interface interface_0{0};
Some_interface interface_1{1};

const char global_message[] ="global_message";
Timer_task timer_task{interface_1.send_data((void*)global_message,strlen(global_message))};


int main()
{

    const char message_0[] ="123456";
    const char message_1[] ="1256";
    while(1)
    {
        interface_0.send_data((void*)message,strlen(message));
        interface_1.send_data((void*)message,strlen(message));
        delay();
    }
}
```

Where data_to_send are filled form main and also form other method called from another interrupt.

We can also set all_data_send_callback if we want to.

Comment: Using an `std::function` (i.e. calling the function bound to it) won't do any allocation. It's the creation of an `std::function` object that might allocate. If you're certain you will never reassign interrupt handlers from within an interrupt, then you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: It seems you have right, i took some measurements and find out when i make std:: function in global scope like `std::function<uint32_t(void)> fun =some_task;` it call simple new placement like`void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept {return ptr}`. When i call std::function localy for ex. in main i don't even need _sbrk function. But what if i wont to use it (and other containers) wide in my event driven code?

Comment: First important question: what compiler/board support are you using? It is quite possible that `std::function` isn't even available.

Comment: Why do you want to use `std::function`? The code in the question doesn't need it.

Comment: I forgot about most important information: I use arm-none-eabi-g++.exe (bleeding-edge-toolchain) 9.1.0. I have --specs=nano.spesc linker flag, and use newlib-nano. Std::function is available for shore. @TarickWelling

Comment: Because it is much clearer if i have for ex. 
`class_vector[interrupt_number] =std::bind(std::mem_fn(methode),object);` instead of some dirty reinterpret_cast, and i want to use it (and also containers) i many other places in code with a lot of interrupts @PeteBecker

Comment: @Marcus -- so show the code that you want to write. `std::function` tends to be overused, and you haven't yet given a compelling reason for adding the complications that it involves. The code you've shown should work just fine.

Comment: @PeteBecker I add some additional code to my question to clarify what I want to achieve, please take a look.